# Rolling dice possible outcome

Tags: permutations, combinations, dice

Can you help me to find the solution to the following question?

> Fifty identical dice are rolled. How many distinct outcomes with positive even number of 1’s, 2’s, ..., of 6’s are possible? For example, 8 of them 1, 14 of them are 2, 10 of them are 3, 10 of them are 4, 2 of them are 5, 6 of them are 6.

I am trying to write 50 as sum of even numbers such that $50 = 50 + 0$, $50 = 48 + 2$, $50 = 46 + 4$, $50 = 46 + 2 + 2$, etc.

By using this method, I can solve this question. I am curious to know about any other methods.

Comment: [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683548/fifty-identical-dice-are-rolled-how-many-distinct-out-comes-with-positive-even) was asked a little while ago.

Comment: @lulu Which was then deleted by the OP shortly after receiving an answer. :sigh:

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you do not care about the order in which the numbers are rolled... Any way of rolling twenty $2$'s and thirty $3$'s will be considered the same, whether the $2$'s appeared first or the $3$'s appeared first or they appeared mixed.

Letting $x_i$ represent the number of times that the number $i$ was rolled for each $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ respectively, you are trying to count the number of non-negative integer solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6 = 50\\0\leq x_i\\x_i~\text{even}\end{cases}$

As for a hint... recall that if $x_i$ is even then it can be written as $x_i=2y_i$ for some $y_i$.

Further, [Stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is a common technique/explanation for how to proceed.